# MotionLayout with onSwipe handler on NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-nestedscrollview, android-motionlayout

I tried to set an onSwipe handler on a NestedScrollView to drive the animation in a MotionLayout.
However the first time the animation doesn't work. But if I start the animation d, then the onSwipe handler begins to work as expected.
Here is the relevant code for the NestedScrollView:

```
        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nsv_desc"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/slider_view"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            android:background="?colorSurface">
```

...

```
        <Constraint android:id="@+id/nsv_desc">
        <Layout
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/slider_view"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_all_large"
                motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_all_normal" />
        <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="elevation"
                motion:customDimension="0dp" />
    </Constraint>
```

...

```
        <OnSwipe
        motion:touchAnchorId="@id/nsv_desc"
        motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
        motion:touchAnchorSide="top"/>
```

...

```
            <KeyAttribute
                motion:motionTarget="@id/nsv_desc"
                motion:framePosition="25"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:translationY="40dp" />
```

EDIT: SOLUTION
I fixed the bug. It turned out that it was very specific to my app. For anyone interested:
suppose you have multiple ConstraintSets and transitions between them, like A -> B -> C -> D ecc.
If you transition (with the onSwipe handler or programmatically) from A to B and reach the state B, then you have to call motionLayout.setTransition to specify that your motion layout must now apply the transition from B to C when you swipe on the widgets.
If you call the transition from B to C programmatically it automatically applies that transition (that's the reason of the behavior described in the question).

Comment: Be sure the NestedScrollView tag is child of the MotionLayout not grandchildren

Comment: It is. It's strange because if I start the animation programmatically, from then on the on swipe anchor works as expected.